# How do I bind style to onclick element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sass, pug

Whenever I click on the left arrow icon, I want the style of the menu to change. Is it possible to bind specific css style when using onclick function?

```
i.fas.fa-chevron-circle-left.left
```

```
#sidebar-container .menu
  width: 18rem
  transition: 200ms
```

How I want it to look after onclick function.

```
#sidebar-container .menu
  width: 10rem
```

Comment: split your styles into 2 different classes, now assign those classes to an element using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class containing the styles you want and you can toggle those on and off using javascript:

`document.getElementById('my-element').classList.toggle('my-class');`

This will add the `my-class` class if the element doesnt have it, and remove the `my-class` class if the element does have it. You may also use `classList.add` and `classList.remove` if you'd like to set it on or off.

You can easily bind this to a button with inline javascript. It is recomended to use event listeners but this should do the trick:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('my-element').classList.toggle('my-class')">Click me to toggle the class</button>
```

You can change `my-elemment` to be the ID of the element you want to toggle the class for and `my-class` to the classname you'd like to use.

Comment: It doesn't work properly, instead of the menu width, it changes the width of the icon.

Comment: @Dave make sure the ID you're toggling the class on is set to the menu and not the icon.

Comment: .menu width is 18 rem, minimized width is seperate class with 10 rem
`(onclick="document.getElementById('left').classList.toggle('minimized')")`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to bind to an element. You can use document.querySelector() to find that element.

for example:

```
const el = document.querySelector("i.fas.fa-chevron-circle-left.left")

el.addEventListener("click", function(){
  el.style.transition = "";
});
```

It's almost always easier to just add an overriding class instead of editing single style properties:

```
el.classList.add("override");
```

and have that class in css somewhere.

```
.override {
    transition: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a secondary class for styles you want when it is clicked. You can toggle the class like this

```js
const menu = document.querySelector("#sidebar-container .menu");

menu.addEventListener('click', function () {
// by adding class name
  menu.classList.toggle("menu-clicked");
});
```

```css
#sidebar-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all ease 200ms;
}

#sidebar-container .menu {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidebar-container .menu.menu-clicked {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-container">
  <div class="menu">
    Menu
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!